# How to set and get Cookies in Laravel 5.8?

Tags: laravel, session, cookies

This is the code I use to set Cookies.

```
Cookie::queue("utm_source", "google" , 43200);
```

And this is the code I use to get a Cookie:

```
dd(Cookie::get('utm_source'));
```

And when I use dd(), this is always null.

I did many workarounds and I cannot get this working. Any suggestions please?

And is there any other methods to do this using sessions maybe?

I simply need to have some values and use then in other views.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you queueing the cookie on the same request as you do the dd()? Because, ::queue only *queues* the cookie to be sent with the **next** response. If you dd() right after, the request gets broken off and the cookie does not get sent with the request. Try removing the dd() and put that dd() on another URL. Do the request that sets the cookie, and then open the URL with the dd() to see if the cookie got set.

Comment: @Roboroads I tried that and still not working.. I really want to set Cookie here and get it in the last page. But no good..

Comment: Can you confirm via your browser DevTools that the cookie is actually set?

Comment: Yeah I checked and it is there.. And Cookie is encrypted too.

Comment: And I used session()->put( 'utm_source', $parameters["utm_source"]); and then I was trying to get this value using $utm_source = session( 'utm_source' ); in another view. but this doesn't work too.. Confusing